# How to redirect home page to another page after login for all user?

Tags: plugin-development, login, wp-redirect, template-redirect

How to change home page to another page after login for all user roles, not a specific one?

Comment: Do you mean redirect to another URL? Or do you mean show different things on the homepage to logged in users?

Answer (score 1):

By adding this to your theme **functions.php** file:

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
  return home_url('/');
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin, like 'Redirect After Login' (https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/)

Or you can do it manually by adding this to your **functions.php**

```
function admin_new_page() {
  return '/new-page-url';
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_new_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard WordPress function that you can use for this

`<?php 
// Check if user if logged in. If so, redirect to www.example.com
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    header("Location:http://www.example.com");
}
?>`